# How to override method that uses raw types?

Tags: java, generics, raw-types

I have the following legacy class that I can not change:

```java
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class SuperClass
{
   // ...

   public Logger getLogger(Class c) {
      // ...
   }
}
```

I want to override the `getLogger` method in my class. Is it possible to do it without [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) usage?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what would you rather use instead of `Class c`? `Class<?>`?

Comment: No, you're stuck with using raw generic. Which shouldn't be an issue, you just need to add `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` next to `@Override`, so you don't get any compiler warnings.

Comment: @ernest_k Yes, `Class<?>` would be acceptable, but I can not use it

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I know about it, just want to be sure there is no another cleaner alternative.

Comment: Sorry, if you're stuck with code that predates Java 5, i.e. Java code from 2004 or earlier, you just have to live with the quirks.

Comment: Which Logger are you using?  Log4j?

Comment: @Dale This is a third party library that uses `java.util.logging` but general part of my application uses Log4j and I need to provide an adapter here.

Comment: So should it use Log4j or ???

Comment: @Dale I use `java.util.logging.Logger` in this method, I have updated the question, but I do not see how it can help with answer to the question.

Comment: One option would be to update your dependencies. Get rid of that version of `SuperClass`, and get a newer one instead.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you cannot override. It also makes sense, because overriding simply means Whatever that can be done with super-class can also be done with sub-class. If SuperClass `getLogger` can take `Class` (of all kinds) then the sub-class should also allow that.

In this case, you could create bridge methods if that fits your purpose:

```
class SubClass<T> extends SuperClass {

    @Override
    public Logger getLogger(Class c) {
        return getLoggerT(c);
    }

    public Logger getLoggerT(Class<T> c) {
        return super.getLogger(c);
    }
}
```

And this class can be used through out.

Comment: I can not understand why we can not use `Class<?> c` instead of `Class c`. Why this is not allowed?